# Main idea of the proof of the Galois solvability criterion

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory, solvable-groups

For an oral exam I want to learn the proof of the Galois solvability criterion (Galois 1831).

I have already seen the proof online, I tried to understand it but it is incredibly long.

Could someone explain the proof idea to me by dividing the proof in some steps?

Since it is an oral exam I don't have to rewrite each passage. I just need to explain the key concepts of the proof and the different steps in short words.

The Galois solvability criterion:

Let $K$ be a field with $Char(K) = 0$. Let $f ∈ K[T]$.

Exactly then the equation $f(x) = 0$ can be solved by radicals if the group $Gal(f /K)$ is solvable.

Thank you for any help

Comment: While you say that you don't need to be able to reproduce every detail of every step of the proof, I still feel like the best way to learn how to do a rougher, less detailed version of the proof it to familiarise yourself with the full proof. Not necessarily learn to reproduce it by heart, but reading through it, making sure you agree with each step. Then you can look at how the proof was written, and try to find the division between the steps yourself.